# Spotify can't play this right now. If you have the file on your computer you can Error Message Kubuntu 23.04

Tags: kubuntu, spotify

Has anyone gotten error message from Spotify Client App:
[image]

Error Message says:

"Spotify can't play this right now. If you have the file on your computer you can import it"

**Troubleshoot Steps I have tried**

1. [linux error: Spotify can't play this right now. If you have the file on your computer you can](https://community.spotify.com/t5/Desktop-Linux/linux-error-Spotify-can-t-play-this-right-now-If-you-have-the/td-p/4677307)

***Feedback***:
I already have libavcodec57, libavformat57 packages installed on my system. it didnt work for me.

2. [How to fix the Permission denied error in Flatpak](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-fix-the-permission-denied-error-in-flatpak)

***Feedback***

I though it would be permission issues from flatpak. I uninstall flatpak and reinstalled it. It didn't work for me.